# Regex Error for Cucumber Step Definition

Tags: java, cucumber

I am unable to execute the below Cucumber scenario due to error in my step definition file for my when step

```
"User Selects <Origin>, <Destination>, <Date> and <MonthYear>".
```

Regular expression for Date and MonthYear have some problem. I have added my Cucumber Scenario and snippet of my step definition

```
Cucumber Feature:

Scenario Outline: User Searches One Way Flight
Given User is logged into the application
When User selects One way trip
And User Selects <Origin>, <Destination>, <Date> and <MonthYear>
Then Search results should be displayed.

Examples:

    | Origin        | Destination | Date | MonthYear      |
    | New York      | Sydney      | 20   | January 2016   |
```

Step Definition

```
@When("^User Selects \"([^\"]*)\", \"([^\"]*)\", \"(\\d+)\" and \"([\\d+]*)\"$")
public void user_selects(String origin, String destination, String date, String monthYear) {
    flight.searchOneWayFlight(origin, destination, date, monthYear);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `int` for the date and the regular expression from monthYear will not pass the month part.

```
@Given("^User Selects (.*?), (.*?), (\\d+) and (.*?)$")
    public void userSelects(String origin, String destination, int date, String monthYear)
```